# Getting all permutations of columns

Tags: r, permutation

I am trying to pass all permutations of columns as a dataframe to a function, and I cant quite get my code to work. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
require(combinat)
indicators<-data.frame(a=c(1),b=c(2),c=c(3),d=c(4))
cols<-lapply(1:dim(indicators)[2],function(x)rbind(t(permn(1:(dim(indicators)[2]-x)))))
cols[[2]]
temp<-t(apply(cols[[2]],1,function(x){}))
```

GOAL

```
dataframe containing col: 
1
2
3
4
1,2
1,3
1,4
2,3
2,4
....
```

My function:

```
#takes in dataframe of columns
blackBox<-function(x){}
```

Because my original explanation wasnt clear enough: I am trying to get the columns returned in each case into a dataframe so I can do something with the data.

```
#testing only with the first 12 values because otherwise it takes forever
lapply(v1[1:12],function(x){
    colsCombo<-indicators[,c(eval(parse(text=x)))]
    colnames(colsCombo)
    })
```

Comment: In the `permn`, the second argument is function.

Comment: Thanks for that, I fixed the permn parameters

Comment: It looks like you want the power set, which is offered by a few different packages https://www.google.com/#q=cran+power+set Regarding "I am trying to get the columns returned in each case into a dataframe so I can do something with the data" -- that would just be to waste memory; I'm pretty sure there's no advantage in it vs looping over the indices and subsetting to construct your data set within the loop.

Comment: Definitely true, I just didnt know how else to pass the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could loop through the sequence of the columns, get the `combn` of the `unlst`ed elements and use `rapply` to `paste` the elements in each of the nested `list`.

```
Un1 <- unlist(indicators)
lst <- lapply(seq_along(Un1), function(i) combn(Un1, i, simplify=FALSE))
v1 <- rapply(lst, toString)
v1
#[1] "1"   "2"   "3"   "4"   "1, 2"   "1, 3"   "1, 4"  "2, 3"      
#[9] "2, 4"  "3, 4"  "1, 2, 3"  "1, 2, 4"  "1, 3, 4"  "2, 3, 4"  "1, 2, 3, 4"

d1 <- data.frame(v1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

If we need to replace 'v1' by the column names, we can try with `chartr` to replace the index with the column names.

```
rp1 <- paste(colnames(indicators),collapse="")
pt1 <- paste(seq_along(Un1), collapse="")
chartr(pt1, rp1, v1)
#[1] "a"          "b"          "c"          "d"          "a, b"       "a, c"       "a, d"       "b, c"      
#[9] "b, d"       "c, d"       "a, b, c"    "a, b, d"    "a, c, d"    "b, c, d"    "a, b, c, d"
```

Or it could also be done within the `combn` by passing the `names` instead of the values.

```
lst <- lapply(seq_along(Un1), function(i) combn(names(Un1), i, simplify=FALSE))
v1 <- rapply(lst, toString)
v1
#[1] "a"          "b"          "c"          "d"          "a, b"       "a, c"       "a, d"       "b, c"      
#[9] "b, d"       "c, d"       "a, b, c"    "a, b, d"    "a, c, d"    "b, c, d"    "a, b, c, d"
```

Comment: Your solution worked great, but my explanation wasnt clear enough. I added an example (based on your code) about my end goal. Any chance you could update your code?

Comment: @Rilcon42  DO you need `sapply(v1[1:12], function(x) toString(names(indicators[as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ", ")))])))`

Comment: That was it, Thanks!